# when and where to put @class declarations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, class

I am working on a project with several custom classes.  I have a `CardModel` (NSObject) that has some integer properties to hold data, and a `Deck` (NSObject) that has an array to hold a bunch of `CardModels` and then a `CardView` (UIView) that has a `CardModel` as a property that I make when I select a `CardModel` from a `Deck`.  And then I've got a bunch of `UIViewControllers` that I move around on a `UINavigationController`.

My question is about where and when to use the `@class` compiler directive.

If I subclass a `UIViewController` by making a new file and subclassing it, should I use the `@class MyViewController` in the header of `MyViewController.h` or `.m` and does it go in the header of the file that actually uses the controller (like when one controller is going to instantiate another controller type and push it to the stack).  Or do I need to use it at all?  Is it only required if I actually add new properties to my class beyond what's in the stock implementation?  It seems like I'm putting `@class` all over the place just make sure I don't get errors but I don't fundamentally understand when I need it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use it in the .h to inform it about a custom class without including the .h for the custom class.

Example:
Two custom classes: Car and Wheel

```
Car.h
----------------
@interface Car : NSObject {
}
- (void)addWheel:(Wheel*)newWheel;
@end
```

Car.h doesn't know about the class 'Wheel' so it would throw an error so you could import the Wheel.h like so:

```
Car.h
----------------
#import "Wheel.h"

@interface Car : NSObject {
}
- (void)addWheel:(Wheel*)newWheel;
@end
```

BUT you dont need to do this either. Car.h doesn't need to know anything about the Wheel class, it just needs to know it exists. So what you use is the @class to just say that "Hey, this class exists. Take my word for it."

```
Car.h
----------------
@class Wheel;

@interface Car : NSObject {
}
- (void)addWheel:(Wheel*)newWheel;
@end
```

Then inside of the Car.m, when you actually need to know about the Wheel class (properties, methods, etc) you should import the Wheel.h there.

Comment: Thanks - that seems pretty clear.  @class in the header tells that header that references to that class are ok.  Then an #import of the .h file in the corresponding .m file gives the implementation access to all of the actual properties and methods of the class.  But is this only true for things that are subclassed from NSObject, or all superclasses?  Would it be correct to say that any time I make a "new file" and choose a subclass, I'll need to follow this, and any time I just instantiate a class in my code that is a regular class, I don't?

Comment: All superclasses, too.   `@class X` is simply shorthand for "there exists a class X for which there can be pointers".  Nothing more, nothing less.  It is only needed when you can't import the header for the class first (typically, in the PCH file).

Comment: So I may have the same `@class x` directive in multiple headers, so long as those headers need to know about `x`, either as a property or in a method they implement, right?  Starting to solidify in my mind - thanks!

Comment: Simpler still; you can put `@class X;` wherever you want, whether or not you even need it. It does very little beyond enabling `X *` based declarations.  It is up to you to use it sparingly.

Comment: So the PCH (precompiled header?) file has the information about all the typical objects and is why I don't need to tell the compiler about things like UIButton or UIViewController ahead of time?

Comment: If you look in the pch, there's a section that has
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
which imports the UIKit stuff which has all the standard, vanilla stuff (like UIButton and UIViewController)

Answer (score 4):

The `@class` directive is used when you need a header to know about a class but you don't want to import the class's header file; e.g., when you need to avoid circular dependencies.