# Cyclic dependencies

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am confused about Cyclic dependencies. I have two .m file and I need used those two files in each other.

For example two files A.h/A.m and B.h/.m Now I have to access the variable of file A.h/.m into B.h/.m and the variable of file B.h/.m into A.h/.m I import A.h into B.h and B.h into A.h But it gives an error.

And ya I don't want to use Delegate file ! is there any way to do the same without Delegate file ?

Thanks..

Comment: Is it using CMake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably place the #imports in the .m file instead of the .h
You may need to forward declare the classes if you reference them in the .h

Comment: ya error get solved but now the value of variable is null... the variable is NSMutableArray that is declared in A.h file and I am allocating memory in B.m class. I also tried to allocating memory in A.m file but still it shows null values..

Comment: @maulik I'd have to see the code to understand it.  Perhaps start a new question, as I doubt it's a dependency problem anymore.

Answer (score 2):

From [What is the difference between @class and #import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361077/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-import)

@class is used to avoid circular dependency... This prevents circular references where in one header A imports a second header B which(B) imports the first(A) which imports the second (B)and so on in an endless cycle....@class is generally used to ask compiler to look for its definition at runtime... especially when it resides in some static library..

Pls see this too

[when and where to put @class declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258892/when-and-where-to-put-class-declarations)

Comment: ya error get solved but now the value of variable is null... the variable is NSMutableArray that is declared in A.h file and I am allocating memory in B.m class. I also tried to allocating memory in A.m file but still it shows null values..

Comment: I am not sure if u will be able to access values that way. the use of delegates is preferred to such purposes